# How to use Jeditable with hoverintent

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jeditable, hoverintent

I'd like to make my fields editable with the hoverIntent(plugin) event. So a user hovers over a field for about a second and the field displays in edit mode. I've tried a few approaches and haven't gotten it to work. Any suggestions? Here are the approaches I tried:

**Approach 1 - Using JEditable plugin parameter (couldn't figure out the setup)**

```
 $('.dle_textfield 17').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
     indicator : 'Saving...',
     plugin: function (settings,original){
     var config={
       over:function(){},
       interval:500,
       out:function(){}
     }  
       $('.dle_textfield 17').hoverIntent(config);
     }
 });
```

**Approach 2 - Using hoverintent and hover events**

*This approach worked but would require the secondary hover event to fire (user hovers out of and back on the field). This is a bad user experience. I'd like the mouse to not have to move and become editable.

```
var config={
  over:test,
  interval:500,
  out:function(){}
}   
function test() {
   $('.dle_textfield.17').attr('class','edittest 17');
   $('.edittest.17').live('hover',function(){
        $('.edittest.17').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
          indicator : 'Saving...',
          event:'hover'
         });
    });
 }

$('.dle_textfield').hoverIntent(config);
```